# How to shutdown ExecuterService in java, when created in constructor..?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a Java application (a POC) without using any framework. in one of the classes I have initialized `ExecuterService` in the constructor, now I am not sure how to shutdown it, `public void finalize (){}` method not working. can anyone help me with this...??

```
public class SomeClass{

private ExecutorService executorService;

public SomeClass(){
   executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
}


/*
//This wont work
public void finalize(){
    executorService.shutdown();
}

*/
```

Thank You...

Comment: `.shutdown`, `.shutdownNow` or `.awaitTermination` choose your weapon accroding to your needs.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the executor service after the constructor is finished. Typically in a private instance field.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, but that's what my question is, how/where to shutdown...?? because I have initiated  ```ExecuterService``` in the constructor.

Comment: Ole, can you please elaborate...?? did not get it.

Comment: When do you want your service shut down and why? Though it’s a good thing to do in production code, it may not be necessary in a POC? (Your code in the edit does what I suggested.)